# I ran the code and got this error TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: arcpy, python, arcgis-10.0, shapefile, polyline-creation

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

def polylineArea(x, y): # this is your function definition
   count=len(xlist)
   area=0
   j=count-1
   for i in range (0, count):
       area+=((x[j]+x[i])*(y[j]-y[i]))
       j=i
   return area*.5

infile=open("C:/KateFiles/Courses/SIE510/ParcelStuff/parcel15.txt", "r")
outputname = "C:/KateFiles/Courses/SIE510/ParcelStuff/P_12/ParcelPolys2.shp"

sr=arcpy.SpatialReference(102683)
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(os.path.dirname(outputname),os.path.basename(outputname),"POLYLINE", spatial_reference=sr)
arcpy.AddField_management(outputname, "ParcelID", "LONG", field_precision=8)
arcpy.AddField_management(outputname, "Map", "TEXT", field_length=4)
arcpy.AddField_management(outputname, "Lot", "TEXT", field_length=4)
arcpy.AddField_management(outputname, "point", "Float", field_precision=10, field_scale=2)
cursor1 = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outputname,("ParcelID","SHAPE@", "Map","Lot", "point"))

header1 = infile.readline()
print header1 # print this out so you can see what this contains
header2 =header1.split()# split the header parts by white space
parcelID=header2[1]#assign parcel ID
Mapno=header2[2]# assign the Mapno
Lotno=header2[3]# assign the Lotno
xlist=[]
ylist=[]

#poly =[] # A list that will hold each of the Polygon objects
#point=arcpy.point
parray=arcpy.Array()
# Loop over lines and extract variables of interest 
for line in infile: 
   segments=line.split()   
   x=float(segments[0]) # gets x
   y=float(segments[1]) # gets y
   print x, y
   pt=arcpy.Point(x, y)
   parray.add(pt)

   xlist.append(x)
   ylist.append(y)

area=polylineArea(x, y) # this is your function call
print area
point=arcpy.polyline(parray) 

row=(parcelID, poly, Mapno, Lotno, point) # these match the fields in your insert cursor specification
cursor1.insertRow(row)
infile.close()
```

```
OUTPUT, 
Feature: 15 R34 030

908946.59 421204.23
908642.29 420764.59
908479.99 420878.46
908394.73 420761.41
908352.74 420703.76
908348.19 420697.53
908103.16 420865.53
908110.95 420869.92
908314.03 420984.18
908362.5 421011.53
908319.76 421217.07
908294.32 421329.6
908287.91 421361.69
908343.47 421365.32
908483.78 421374.47
908568.12 421379.98
908911.43 421403.04
908946.59 421204.23
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ahmed A. Jasim/Desktop/b.py", line 51, in <module>
    area=polylineArea(x, y) # this is your function call
  File "C:/Users/Ahmed A. Jasim/Desktop/b.py", line 9, in polylineArea
    area+=((x[j]+x[i])*(y[j]-y[i]))
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>>
```

Comment: Don't completely change the question. Ask a new one instead (after doing some research on arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is `arcpy.Point`, with a capital P.

Note that you will also need to change `arcpy.Polyline`

Comment: JGH, thanks I did do your correction, and it works but I got this error now :     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ahmed A. Jasim/Desktop/b.py", line 51, in <module>
    area=polylineArea(x, y) # this is your function call
  File "C:/Users/Ahmed A. Jasim/Desktop/b.py", line 9, in polylineArea
    area+=((x[j]+x[i])*(y[j]-y[i]))
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'                                                     How can I fix it

Comment: @AhmedJasim For your second question, you are passing a float (one value) but then treat it as an array (multiple values). One of the 2 is wrong.

Comment: JGH , sorry I didn't understand your point much, could you please explain this point more simply? I appreciate your helping.

Comment: I think you should learn some Python basics before asking others to debug your bad code.